# Server side pagination in UI-GRID of angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I know how to do Client side pagination using UI-GRID of AngularJS. But I want to know Server-side pagination using UI-GRID of AngularJS. Means on clicking on next page, results of only next page are retrieved from Server and shown to the user. I have searched alot but could not found any PROPER solution.

It would be great if you could provide Plunker as sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework use `Take and Skip` extension method with the help of `OrderBy` like

```
context.YourTable.OrderByDescending(sort).Skip(skipRows).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

If you are using sql queries then use `OFFSET and FETCH` with the help of `order by` like

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable order by SomeRow desc 
OFFSET @skipRows -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

**Strategy**

1. Pass the PageSize to the server side function or API as pageSize (say 10)
2. Pass the skipRows to the server side. So suppose you are on page 3 then

   skipRows = pageSize * (page -1)

So when you are on page 3 then skipRows value will become `(10 * 2 = 20)` and hence from server side you will get the next `10 rows` after skipping `20 rows`.

**EDIT 1 : How to setup the UI Grid**

Set `useExternalPagination` true and use `gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged` to track the page changes and get the data

You can refer this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UttxPkXG8fYQDX85fnyZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I know how to do in Enitity Framework. My question is how to do it in UI-Grid. How to call it against page in UI-GRID. It would be great if you or anybody can provide Plunker.

Comment: Ashish, the plunker you provided retrieves all data from server and then do slicing at client side. I actually want a scenario in which only selected data is retrieved from server to UI-GRID.

Comment: @user6389905 then don't do slicing. just take the corresponding data and pass it to $scope.gridOptions.data